# What killed Beagle?

Tags: history

[Beagle](http://beagle-project.org/Main_Page) was all the rage some years ago, and then it just died... silently. Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lack of time and support by Novell.

From a thread in their mailing list:

> A couple people mentioned whether Novell or Canonical (Ubuntu) would
>   fund Beagle development.  I used to work at Novell, and I had the
>   great fortune of working on Beagle pretty much from the start.  For a
>   couple of years there they paid two full time developers to work on
>   the project: Jon Trowbridge and myself.  When Jon left the company, it
>   was just me -- although there was occasional part-time help, like Dan
>   Winship's excellent work on the search UI.  Since I left Novell nearly
>   two years ago, there has been none.  I think it's safe to say that
>   Novell no longer has any dedication to the project.  I don't mean that
>   as a dig -- having worked on Ximian and SUSE distributions you have to
>   make strategic and tactical decisions where to put your resources,
>   since you can't hack full time on everything.  It appears clear that
>   desktop search hasn't panned out as they thought and that experimental
>   projects like Dashboard, Association Browser, etc. aren't feasible.
>
> As for Canonical and Ubuntu, a number of releases ago that community
>   decided to go with Tracker instead of Beagle, I believe in part due to
>   a major backlash against Mono following the Microsoft/Novell patent
>   agreement.  Although I think Beagle is still for the moment ahead of
>   Tracker in terms of core user functionality, Tracker has a vibrant
>   development community backed by open source companies whereas Beagle's
>   is completely stagnant and bordering on nonexistent.  If I were an
>   impartial party trying to decide in which to invest development
>   resources, Beagle is simply a tougher case to make.

Read the thread [here](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/dashboard-hackers/2009-September/msg00005.html)